# how to perform delete operation using link button or hyperlink or a href

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

i want to perform delete operation using `a herf` or `LinkButton` or `HyperLink`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("ID","~/Persons.aspx?ID={0}") %>' OnClick="lnkDelete_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

StoredProcedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDeletePerson
    @Id int
AS
BEGIN
    Delete from tblpersons where ID = @Id
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


END
GO
```

i want to stay on same page and to perform delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not set `NavigateUrl` - that'll take you to other page. Instead the code should look like:

```
<asp:LinkButton CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>' ID="lnkDelete" 
  Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClick="lnkDelete_Click" />
```

Notice the `CommandArgument` property - basically you can assign any custom string to this property and it will be passed to your OnClick handler (in this case we're passing there id).

Code behind:

```
protected void lnkDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var button = (IButtonControl)sender;
  // grab the id from CommandArgument property
  int id = Convert.ToInt32(button.CommandArgument, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  // call stored procedure based on id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try this for get id

```
LinkButton lnkDelete= (LinkButton )sender;

ID= Common.CInt(lnkDelete.CommandArgument.Split(',')[0]);
```